# Canvas draw path in android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am a new beginner in android and I want to make a simple program that detect touch coordinates and draw a circle and path of touch, I make a simple program that draw a circle around the touch and follow it but I still can do the path of touch. When I start the program with path it crash, when I remove the path it works normal...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    LinearLayout layout; //declarea variabilor pentru desenarea cercului

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //specificarea 
        layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout); //gasirea id 
        layout.addView(new CustomView(MainActivity.this));
    }

    public class CustomView extends View { //crearea unei mape pentru canvas
        Bitmap mBitmap;
        Paint paint;
        Path path;

        public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(640, 1024, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            paint = new Paint();
            path = new Path();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);//culoare cercului desenat
            paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {//desenarea cercului la atingere
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 25, paint);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        int action = event.getAction();

        switch (action){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
                path.lineTo(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
            default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are `x` and `y` declared? What does happen with your code and what should happen?

Comment: x and y are for center of circle that is draw when touch screen, the program need to detect touch and show a coordinates of screen and draw circle around the touch and path for siwpe touch

Comment: I got that. I asked where `x` and `y` are declared, not what they are used for. You need to provide a little more detail about the problem you are facing. You have not explained what is actually happening when you run your code. Is a circle drawn at all? Does it move when the touch moves? As it is, your post isn't much better than "Here's my code. It isn't working. How can I fix it?"

Comment: sorry I just added the declaration of `x` and `y`, the problem is that it didn't  work when i try to draw `Path`, if i remove it from code it work, it detect my touch and circle follow it on movement on screen.

Comment: When you try to draw `path`, what _does_ happen? Does the program crash? Is nothing drawn (even the circle)? Or is it that the path does not appear and everything else works the same?

Comment: when i start the program with path it crash, when i remove path it work normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not initializing `path`. Most likely, your program is crashing with a `NullPointerException`. Try adding this inside the `CustomView` constructor:

```
path = new Path();
```

In the future, when you are posting about your Android program crashing, it would be most helpful if you posted the logcat output from a crash.